# GraphQL and Socket.io on the same NestJS doesn't allow the transport protocol to be 'websockets' from angular

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, graphql, nestjs

I'm seeing an issue where when I have GraphQL and socket.io running on the same NestJS API server, socket.io will not connect with websockets, it only establishes a connection with long polling.

if I comment out the import for my GraphQL in my app.module, I'm able to connect with a websocket transport protocol.  I assume that GraphQL is somehow refusing the connection to the socket.io server on websockets but I have no idea how to get around that.

If I force the transport protocol to be websockets on both ends (my angular and nestjs), it connects fine when graphql is not included, but it won't connect at all when GraphQL is included.

I'm close to the point of abandoning GraphQL, or moving it to its own app engine service, but I'd really like for this to work on the same API instance.

any ideas?

TIA

EDIT: adding my package.json from the nest project so you can see versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^0.4.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/graphql": "7.3.4",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/passport": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.0.7",
"@nestjs/swagger": "^4.5.5",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^7.0.7",
"@nestjs/cli": "7.1.2",
"apollo-server": "2.12.0",
"apollo-server-express": "2.12.0",
"class-transformer": "0.2.3",
"class-validator": "0.12.2",
"graphql": "14.6.0",
"graphql-subscriptions": "1.1.0",
"passport": "^0.4.1",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rimraf": "^3.0.2",
"rxjs": "^6.5.4",
"swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4"
```

},

Comment: I just came across a similar scenario when I use GraphQL subscribers, NestJS Socket Gateway stopped working. Since both are trying to use the same port, I am guessing there might be some conflicts. Did you find the solution for your case?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan I did not.  I asked on the NestJS discord and got some responses there (definitely check that out if you haven't already) but we decided to just scrap the GraphQL implementation we were working on.  It was creating a bigger barrier to entry for our new people and this was the straw to break the camel's back.  Like I said though, try their discord, they're very responsive there.